# Coefficient value from glmnet

Tags: standardization, glmnet

I am running `glmnet` for the first time and I am getting some weird results.

My dataset has n = 139; p = 70 (correlated variables)

I am trying to estimate the effect of each variable for both, inference and prediction.
I am running:

```
> cvfit = cv.glmnet(X, Y,family = c('gaussian'),alpha = 0.5,intercept = T,standardize = T,nlambda=100,type = "mse")

> coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")
```

From all the 70 estimates, two caught my attention:

```
4           0.5731999

14          5.419356829
```

What bugs me is the fact that:

```
> cor(X[,4],Y)

[1,] 0.674714

> cor(X[,14],Y)

[1,] -0.01742419
```

In addition, if I standardize `X` myself (using `scale(X)`) and run it again:

```
> cvfit = cv.glmnet(scale(X), Y,family = c('gaussian'),alpha = 0.5,intercept = T,standardize = F,nlambda=100,type = "mse")

> coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")
```

I now get that 4 has the highest effect and variable "14" is about 5 times smaller. I couldn't find a good description about the normalization process in glmnet. Any clue as to why this is happening (I don't think its a bug, I just would like to understand why and which one is right)?

PS: I ran this many times, so I know it is not an effect of the sampling during the cross-validation.

Comment: It's not quite clear whether this is a question about software or a question about Statistics.

Comment: It is possible to construct examples where $cor(y,x_1)=0$, $cor(y,x_2)=0$, $cor(y,x_3)>0$ and yet $y=a x_1+b x_2$ thus when you regress $y$ on $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, you will have significant coefficients for $x_1$ and $x_2$ only. That is, bivariate correlations are not informative enough when considering a multivariate regression. In turn, this means your case might be just what it is and not a result of an error.

Comment: Thank you @RichardHardy and SteveS. This question in fact does involve elastic net/statistics. However I perhaps failed to mention the following:
When I run the code with "standardize=F", I get that variable "14" is set to 0 and variable "4" is the highest one.
When I normalize myself:
>X<-scale(RAWdataCovariates)
and run it again with standardize = F, variable "4" is again the highest one, and variable "14", although non-zero is 5 times less than 14.

I couldn't find a good description on the manual of why their standardization is different then standardizing to mean 0 and var 1
thanks

Comment: Thank @SteveS. After I edited my question, the issue became more a standardization issue. I later found this post:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33674/why-do-lars-and-glmnet-give-different-solutions-for-the-lasso-problem

But still could not find a recommendation whether standardize = T is better than x = scale(X) and standardize = F.

Answer (score 12):

I tracked down the standardization process of glmnet and documented it on the thinklab Platform [there](https://thinklab.com/discussion/computing-standardized-logistic-regression-coefficients/205#5). This includes a comparison of the different ways to use standardization with glmnet.

Long story short, if you let glmnet standardize the coefficients (by relying on the default `standardize = TRUE`), glmnet performs standardization behind the scenes and reports everything, including the plots, the "de-standardized" way, in the coefficients' natural metrics.

Comment: It really bothers me that the plots are unstandardized, it makes them very difficult to interpret.

Comment: Hi @Antoine Lizée , thank you for your documentation on thinklab. I have a question. I rescaled the variables myself and set standardize = false. Does that also produce coefficients returned on the original scale? I am confused on whether we need to further standardize those coefficients separately, or if there is a reason for using the unstandardized coefficients?

Comment: @Antoine Lizée Could you please explain why you didn't set `standardize=FALSE` in the [R report](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/antoine-lizee/R-Miscs/blob/adc01ea6d49514efb047c58376126b4480929eeb/Stat-glm_coeffs.html) when you input the standardized data? If you set `standardize=FALSE`, then the coefficients will not be the same.

Answer (score 6):

the package will return transformed coefficients. line 1074 of fortran file in glmnet5.f90 is the transformation of gaussian type, as shown in below.

```
ca(l,k)=ys*ca(l,k)/xs(ia(l))                                          982
```

I believe this transformation may inflate the coef of variables with small standard deviation. If the sd(X) differes in training and testing dataset, I think this may cause bigger mse.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation here: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Glmnet_Vignette.pdf (top of page 8)

It seems that y is also standardized, you could try and rerun your example with the standardized y and see if it matches the result.

Answer (score 0):

standardize = is a flag symbol, tells the status of X prior model fitting. But the result always returns in the form of original scale.

So if you want the glmnet to help you standardize your variables, you should set standardize = FALSE.

Comment: This answer is rather brief by our standards, do you think you could expand on it somewhat?

Comment: Unless I'm mis-reading the documentation, your last sentence is incorrect.  If standardize = F, glmnet doesn't standardize the x , it assumes that is was done prior .

Comment: Well, guess we both should check the documentation again... I was quoting the original documentation acutally.

Comment: this second sentence in this response is wrong, the documentation states: 

• standardize is a logical flag for x variable standardization, prior to fitting the model sequence. The
coefficients are always returned on the original scale. Default is standardize=TRUE.