# Why glmnet gives different coefficient estimates with same data?

Tags: lasso, glmnet, elastic-net

I have been trying to fit a lasso model using `cv.glmnet`. I tried to implement four different models (3 using `cv.glmnet` and 1 using `caret::train`) based on standardization. All the four models gives very different coefficient estimates which I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is a fully reproducible code:

```
library("glmnet")
data(iris)
iris <- iris
dat <- iris[iris$Species %in% c("setosa","versicolor"),]
X <- as.matrix(dat[,1:4])
Y <- as.factor(as.character(dat$Species))

set.seed(123)
model1 <- cv.glmnet(x = X,
                    y = Y,
                    family = "binomial",
                    standardize = FALSE,
                    alpha = 1,
                    lambda = rev(seq(0,1,length=100)),
                    nfolds = 3)

set.seed(123)
model2 <- cv.glmnet(x = scale(X, center = T, scale = T),
                    y = Y,
                    family = "binomial",
                    standardize = FALSE,
                    alpha = 1,
                    lambda = rev(seq(0,1,length=100)),
                    nfolds = 3)
set.seed(123)
model3 <- cv.glmnet(x = X,
                    y = Y,
                    family = "binomial",
                    standardize = TRUE,
                    alpha = 1,
                    lambda = rev(seq(0,1,length=100)),
                    nfolds = 3)

##Using caret
library("caret")

lambda.grid <- rev(seq(0,1,length=100)) #set of lambda values for cross-validation
alpha.grid <- 1 #alpha
trainControl <- trainControl(method ="cv",
                             number=3) #3-fold cross-validation
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.alpha=alpha.grid, .lambda=lambda.grid) #these are tuning parameters to be passed into the train function below

set.seed(123)
model4 <- train(x = X,
                y = Y,
                method="glmnet",
                family="binomial",
                standardize = FALSE,
                trControl = trainControl,                          
                tuneGrid = tuneGrid)

c1 <- coef(model1, s=model1$lambda.min)
c2 <- coef(model2, s=model2$lambda.min)
c3 <- coef(model3, s=model3$lambda.min)
c4 <- coef(model4$finalModel, s=model4$finalModel$lambdaOpt)
c1 <- as.matrix(c1)
c2 <- as.matrix(c2)
c3 <- as.matrix(c3)
c4 <- as.matrix(c4)
```

`model2` scales the independent variables (vector `X`) beforehand and `model3` does so by setting `standardize = TRUE`. So atleast these two models should return identical results - but it is not so.

The lambda.min obtained from the four models are:
model1 = 0
model2 = 0
model3 = 0
model4 = 0.6565657

The coefficient estimates between the models differ drastically too. Why would this be occuring?

Answer (score 2):

You might find this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126109/coefficient-value-from-glmnet) helpful.

Essentially

- c1 are coefficients for unstandardized data (in the original units of
  the data)
- c2 are coefficients for standardized data (in z score
  units)
- c3 are coefficients for standardized data (in original units
  of the data)
- c4 is because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897941/r-caret-train-glmnet-final-model-lambda-values-not-as-specified)