# glmnet vs. lars for computing the lasso

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet, lars

I've seen [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33674/why-do-lars-and-glmnet-give-different-solutions-for-the-lasso-problem) as well as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7057/glmnet-or-lars-for-computing-lasso-solutions) regarding the difference between the `lars` and `glmnet` solution paths for fitting the lasso. From my understanding, `glmnet` uses coordinate descent optimisation to identify its coefficient path. If that is the case, what does the `lars` implementation use to identify its path? Is it the same as coordinate descent?

While the first post provides a simple example, I also wondered how they determine their "best" coefficients from those paths. Further, it doesn't seem particularly efficient to me to have to use a lambda value from the `lars` function with `glmnet`, what if you want to move on from the `lars` package and solely use `glmnet`? How can you trust that you are identifying the right coefficients using the right lambdas?

On more complex examples, I've found that `lars` is able to identify the true regression model using the lasso whereas the `glmnet` method has not. Theoretically, `glmnet` should work in identifying the model correctly, so I'm trying to understand the disconnect.

Thanks.

Comment: How is `lars` able to find the true regression model?  I haven't tested `lars` specifically but every feature selection method I've tried results in a very low probabiilty of finding the "right" model even with simple toy test cases.  That is especially true there there is collinearity.

Comment: I've found that, when determining the `lars` path with the lasso modification. I am able to identify the true regression model (or a very close estimate) for several more complex datasets. From my understanding, I am utilising the function to perform the lasso algorithm by determining the optimal lambda value.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your simulation code where you assess the agreement between selected and true predictors.

Comment: I'd be happy to share and discuss elsewhere regarding the simulations, but I was hoping to determine why the lasso implementation in `lars` identifies a different coefficient path as the lasso implementation with `glmnet`, even when standardising outside of the functions.